# Predicting probability of disease according to a continuous variable adjusting by confusing variables

Tags: r, probability, logistic-regression, predict, marginal-effects

I have a doubt regarding to the R package "margins". I'm estimating a logistic model:

```
modelo1 <- glm(VD ~ VE12 + VE.cont + VE12:VE.cont + VC1 + VC2 + VC3 + VC4, family="binomial", data=data)
```

Where:
`VD2` is a dichotomous variable (1 disease / 0 not disease)
`VE12` is a dichotomous exposure variable (with values 0 an 1)
`VE.cont` a continuous exposure variable
`VCx` (the rest of variables) are confounding variables.

My objective is to obtain predicted probability of disease (`VD2`) for a vector of values of `VE.cont` and for each `VE12` group, but adjusting by `VCx` variables. In other words, I would like to obtain the dose-response line between `VD2` and `VE.cont` by `VE12` group but assuming the same distribution of `VCx` for each dose-response line (i.e. without confounding).

Following the nomenclature of this article (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4052139/) I think that I should do a "marginal standardisation" (method 1) that can be done with stata, but I'm not sure how can I do it with R.
I'm using this syntax (with R):

```
cdat0 <- cplot(modelo1, x="VE.cont", what="prediction", data = data[data[["VE12"]] == 0,], draw=T, ylim=c(0,0.3))

cdat1 <- cplot(modelo1, x="VE.cont", what="prediction", data = data[data[["VE12"]] == 1,], draw=marg"add", col="blue")
```

but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right because this approach gives similar results as using the model without confounding variables and the function `predict.glm`.

```
       modelo0 <- glm(VD2 ~ VE12 + VE.cont + VE12:VE.cont, family="binomial", data=data)
```

Perhaps, I should use the margins option but I don't understand the results because the values obtained in the column `VE.cont` are not in the probability scale (between 0 and 1).

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
margins::margins(modelo1, at=list("VE.cont"=x, "VE12"=c(0,1)), type="response")
```

[This is an example of figure that I would like to obtain:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr0tw.png)

Comment: So what exactly is your specific programming question here? I don't think it's clear what the "right" answer would be. If you need help selecting a statistical model or interpreting the results from a statistical model, you should instead ask over at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic.

Comment: I don't know if I'm using the correct margins syntax to obtain the adjusted probability. Statistically talking I know what I need but I don't know how to obtain it with R and the package margins...